Prove that the number of n-digit binary numbers that have no consecutive 1’s is the Fibonacci number $F_{n+2}$.
Problem Description
I'm reading the book - Book of proof, and I'm currently learning mathematical induction. This is an exercise from the book on page 197, and I'm stuck with it. There's no answer for this exercise, so I'm reaching out for help here.
Here's my proof:

Set $a_{n}$ to be the number of n-digit binary numbers that have no consecutive 1's, and $F_{n}$ to be the n-th Fib number.
for $n=1, a_{1}=2=F_{3}=F_{1+2}$
for $n=2, a_{2}=3=F_{4}=F_{2+2}$
Assume that for $n\ge{3}$, there exists that $a_{n}=F_{n+2}$, which equals to $F_{n}+F_{n+1}$
Now I want to proof that $a_{n+2}=F_{n+4}=F_{n+2}+F_{n+3}$ using the assumption above

I think of the relationship between $a_{n}$ and $a_{n+2}$, and I find that:

To obtain a sequence that is 2 characters longer than the original sequence, just add 1 or 0 to the left and the right side of the original sequence
for the original sequence with length $n$, there are 4 situations:

the left side and the right side are both end with 0. To make the new sequence no consecutive 1's, we could add either 1 or 0 to the both sides.
the left side = 0 , and the right side = 1. To make the new sequence no consecutive 1's, we could add 1 or 0 to the left side, and 0 to the right side.
the left side = 1 , and the right side = 0. We could add 0 to the left side, and 1 or 0 to the right side.
the left side = 1 , and the right side = 1. We could add 0 to both sides.


each of the 4 situations above occupy $\frac{1}{4}$ of $a_{n}$, so for the above 4 situations $$a_{n+2}=4\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot a_{n}+2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot a_{n}+2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot a_{n}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot a_{n}=(2+\frac{1}{4})a_{n}$$
5. for $a_{n}=F_{n+2}=F_{n}+F_{n+1}$, then $$a_{n+2}=(2+\frac{1}{4})F_{n+2}=F_{n+2}+\frac{5}{4}F_{n+2}$$

Here comes my stuck point: I want to proof that $a_{n+2}=F_{n+4}=F_{n+2}+F_{n+3}$，but now I got $a_{n+2}=F_{n+2}+\frac{5}{4}F_{n+2}$. It doesn't make sense. What's wrong with my proof?

Update
I understand what's wrong with my solution with the help of van-der-wolf. He presents me with the solution with 1 digit added each time. In my solution, I step with 2 digits at a time. But the internal mechanism is the same.
The mistake happens at the calculation of $a_{n}$. I thought that each of the 4 situations above occupy $\frac{1}{4}$ of $a_{n}$, but It's not true. What we only know is that, the number of no consecutive 1's n-digit binary numbers is $a_{n}$. So we should only use this conclusion to prove the theorem.
When 1 digit is added to the the sequence of $n$ digits, the first digit may be 1 or 0. If the first digit is 0, then the ramaining sequence of digit must be no consecutive 1's, so the number is $a_{n-1}$. If the first digit is 1, then the second digit must be 0, then the ramaining sequence of digit must be no consecutive 1's, so the number is $a_{n-2}$. In this way, we figured out how many sequences start with $0$ and how many sequences start with $1$.
In my solution, I add 2 digits at a time. The mechanism is the same. For a length $n+2$ sequence:

Left 0, right 0: $a_{n}$
Left 0, right 1: $a_{n-1}$
Left 1: right 0: $a_{n-1}$
Left 1, right 1: $a_{n-2}$

So here we got:
$$
a_{n+2}=a_{n}+a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=F_{n+2}+F_{n+1}+F_{n+1}+F_{n}=F_{n+3}+F_{n+2}=F_{n+4}
$$
QED.
Besides, here we don't need to multiply the number by 2 or 4. For example, if we multiply $a_{n}$ by 4, then we've got $0n0, 1n0, 0n1, 1n1$ four combinations. We don't want them all because some sequences may have consecutive 1s. The reason is the same if we multiply $a_{n-1}$ by 2.
Thank you all for helping me with this question!

Try "strong induction", your inductive step should use the fact that $a_n=F_{n+2}$ and $a_{n+1}=F_{n+3}$ to prove that $a_{n+3} = F_{n+4} = F_{n+3}+F_{n+2}$ — can you see where to go from there? Happy to help more if not :-)

Let $a_n$ be the number of $n$-digit binary numbers that have no consecutive 1's. Clearly, $a_1=2$ ("0","1") and $a_2=3$ ("00","10","01").
Assume now that $n\ge 3$.
If the very first digit of $a_n$ is $0$, any combinations of digits in the remaining $n-1$ positions will satisfy the condition, as long as they do not have consecutive ones.
On the other hand, if the first digit is $1$, we must have $0$ in the second position (to avoid "11"), but then the remaining $n-2$ positions will satisfy the condition, as long as they do not have consecutive ones.
Hence $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. Together with $a_1=2$, $a_2=3$ this uniquely defines the sequence of $a_n$ which coincides with the definition of Fibonacci numbers.
